# Factory Girl + Mongoid embedded documents in fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, embed, mongoid, factory-bot, fixtures

Let’s say you have the following mongoid documents:

```
class User
    include Mongoid::Document
    embeds_one :name
end

class UserName
    include Mongoid::Document
    field :first
    field :last_initial

    embedded_in :user
end
```

How do you create a factory girl factory which initializes the embedded first name and last initial?  Also how would you do it with an `embeds_many` relationship?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I was also looking for this one and as I was researching I've stumbled on a lot of code and did pieced them all together (I wish there were better documents though) but here's my part of the code. Address is a 1..1 relationship and Phones is a 1..n relationship to events.

```
  factory :event do
    title     'Example Event'

    address  { FactoryGirl.build(:address) }
    phones    { [FactoryGirl.build(:phone1), FactoryGirl.build(:phone2)] }
  end

  factory :address do
    place     'foobar tower'
    street    'foobar st.'
    city      'foobar city'
  end

  factory :phone1, :class => :phone do
    code      '432'
    number    '1234567890'
  end

  factory :phone2, :class => :phone do
    code      '432'
    number    '0987654321'
  end
```

(And sorry if I can't provide my links, they were kinda messed up)

Comment: Thanks for this.  I just wasted hours tracking down this problem.

Comment: Note that the phones attribute is an array (the FactoryGirl calls are surrounded by []).  You do not need more than one :phone but it has to be an array if the relation is an embeds_many.  That detail cost me about 4 hours!

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution that allows you to dynamically define the number of embedded objects:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :profile do
    name 'John Doe'
    email 'john@bigcorp.com'
    user

    factory :profile_with_notes do
      ignore do
        notes_count 2
      end

      after(:build) do |profile, evaluator|
        evaluator.notes_count.times do
          profile.notes.build(FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:note))
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This allows you to call `FactoryGirl.create(:profile_with_notes)` and get two embedded notes, or call `FactoryGirl.create(:profile_with_notes, notes_count: 5)` and get five embedded notes.