# Setting up Embedded Mongoid Models with Factory_Girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, mongoid, factory-bot

So I'm playing with Mongoid, Rspec and Factory_Girl and I had some issues with an embedded document.

I had the following models:

```
class Profile    
   include Mongoid::Document

   #Fields and stuff
      embeds_one :address

   validates :address, presence: true 
end

class Address    
   include Mongoid::Document

   #Fields and stuff
      embedded_in :profile 
end
```

So when I defined a factory like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :profile do
    #fields

    address
  end
end
```

I got an error like this:

```
Failure/Error: subject { build :profile }
     Mongoid::Errors::NoParent:

       Problem:
         Cannot persist embedded document Address without a parent document.
       Summary:
         If the document is embedded, in order to be persisted it must always have a reference to it's parent document. This is most likely cause by either calling Address.create or Address.create! without setting the parent document as an attribute.
       Resolution:
         Ensure that you've set the parent relation if instantiating the embedded document direcly, or always create new embedded documents via the parent relation.
```

I got it working by changing the factory to something like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :profile do
    #fields

    after(:build) do |p| 
      p.create_address(FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:address))
    end
  end
end
```

This works but I'm hoping there's a more native Factory_Girl way of doing this. It seems like there should be.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `build_address` instead of `create_address`. In my opinion your factory is broken because you're trying to create an address record before profile record is persisted (created). `build_*` should assign all necessary attributes to the parent model and later it should be persisted along with its embedded relations.

Comment: Fair enough, but is there no way in FactoryGirl to handle this without a callback?

Comment: I don't think so, it's mongodb / mongoid specific stuff.

Answer (score 11):

You can do it this way, too, as referenced in [Factory Girl + Mongoid embedded documents in fixtures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536064/factory-girl-mongoid-embedded-documents-in-fixtures):

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :profile do |f|
    #fields
    address { FactoryGirl.build(:address) }
  end
end
```

Comment: This worked in FactoryGirl 4.4.0 but doesn't seem to work anymore in 4.5.0. See my (so far unanswered) question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29282695/upgrading-to-rails-4-1-5-leads-to-factorygirlinvalidfactoryerror-w-factorygir